# How to separate Service and Activity in Android MVP architecture?

Tags: android, android-activity, service, android-contentprovider, android-mvp

I am working on Android Music-Player. I am using **Service** to play songs, **SQLite Database** to store songs, and **ContentProvider** to access sqlite database. I am confused, how can I maintain connection between service and activity? Should I implement connection between presenter and Service? As I am planning to consider my Service as Model, what will be the best and easiest approach to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the approach described **[here](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-bound-services-and-mvp-12ca9f70c7c7)** - it should help you with decoupling your service from your activity in an MVP architecture.

Comment: thank you @Chornge I have read that already, I got that I can pass the service instance to presenter so presenter can handle all the interaction between Activity and Service. But I am doubtful, are we really decoupling Activity and service this way? is it the only right way?

Comment: yes, you are decoupling them - they don't depend on each other to function, activity code isn't inside service class and service code isn't inside activity class, i.e all the logic is placed inside presenter and u can use contracts to create the connection between an activity (view) and a domain object (service) and they don't need to know about each other. u can use dagger as the dependency injection - this way u can unit test your application using mockito or robolectric.